# Generate OpenApi Specification from existing routers in Vertx

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, vert.x, openapi

I'm trying to generate swagger documentation for a Vert.X Reactive application. The current solution is a static YAML file that is converted to an openapi.json file.

This is an awful lot of work and I'm wondering if there is a way to do this automated. I know there are solutions to do it the other way around, but because it is an existing application this is not a possibility.

I found the following library: https://github.com/outofcoffee/vertx-oas Which is kind of the direction I want to go but sadly isn't up to date.

I expect it to be possible but I'm a little bit stuck right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertx-web-api-contract` mantainer here. Unfortunately, we have no official solution for Vert.x Web to OpenAPI conversion because of the design of Vert.x Web Router APIs.

Starting from the Router there is no way to infer what are the request parameters, their location in the request, their schema, if they are required or not, their style, etc. The same thing applies for response bodies where you can't infer the body schema.

Jax-rs and similar technologies allow this conversion because they describe the request contract using some declarative API (e.g. annotations), so a converter just needs to read this description to translate it to the OpenAPI contract

Francesco